# aws nlb socket.io ssl via copilot

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io, nlb, aws-copilot

## Context

I'm trying to create a load balancer with AWS Copilot that runs socket.io instances.

Locally and in an HTTP environment, I can successfully connect to the socket instance via the load balancer (`ws://{id}.elb.{region}.amazonaws.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket`).

[image: Architecture Diagram]

## Problem

When I'm in the HTTPS context and try to connect, it fails and I get the error message `Error: Websocket error` with no real error message or status code (`wss://{id}.elb.{region}.amazonaws.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket`).

With `ws://` everything works and in `wss://` it does not work.

## Code Snippets

### AWS Copilot manifest.yml

```
name: websocket-service
type: Load Balanced Web Service

http:
  path: '/'
  healthcheck: '/health'

nlb:
  port: 8080/tcp
```

### Server

```
import {Server} from 'https'; // I use HTTPS here

// ...
        this._io = socketIo(server); 
// ...
```

### Client

```
// ... 
    const client = socketClient(url, {
        transports: ['websocket']
    });
// ...
```

### AWS Console

EC2 -> Load Balancing -> Load Balancers -> {target} -> Listeners
[image: Load Balancer Listeners]